# react-simple-maps shos small and not centered map

Tags: reactjs, svg, topojson, react-simple-maps

I'm using react-simple-maps to show a SVG map of Argentina, but the issue is that react-simple-maps shows with a small size the map and is not centered. I tried some things to fix it but I don't understand how to fix it.

It's the codesandbox where there's my code:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-map-forked-9x1bl

Comment: It's because the viewBox you are using. You may try to get the bounding box of the group .rsm-geographies and use the data for a new value of the viewBox. Please read about [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

Comment: Please try viewBox="225 377 40 110"

Comment: thanks so very much, I will figure out about getBBox()

Comment: @FernandoAzarías did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: @CeriWestcott no I didn't figure out

Comment: @FernandoAzarías I believe I figured it out, in your geojson, there is a property called transform: scale[...., ....]. you need to update the scale in the GeoJson instead of the react maps

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issue with the zoom then you can try using the ZoomableGroup at [ZoomableGroup](https://www.react-simple-maps.io/docs/zoomable-group)

you can use it by importing `import { ZoomableGroup } from "react-simple-maps"`

Comment: Thanks, I will try with that approach